# What does --> in C# mean?

Tags: c#

While solving 30 days of code challenges in Hackerrank, I came across the symbol --> in C#. I cannot find any docs for the symbol. I know one thing that, "->" is related to pointers. But I'm not sure what does "-->" mean. The usage is like below.

**Reference:** Hackerrank 30 days of code, Linked list challenge.

```
    while(T-->0)
```

**Note: I was confused between T-- >0 and T-->0 due to poor spacing in website. No input needed further.**

Comment: Search google: `site:stackoverflow.com "-->" operator` The quotes are important. Not sure how to do the same in SO's search.

Comment: I believe that s just 2 operator `--` and `>`

Comment: I checked google by using "". The code will be "T--"  ">" 0  as per logic. Due to poor spacing in the Hackerrank website, I was confused about the existence of "-->" operator.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Adding some space can make that more clear

```
T-- > 0
```